# Array of jump tables in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, jump-table

I'm trying to optimize access to some jump tables I have made, they are as follows:

```
int (*const usart_ctrl_table[USART_READ_WRITE_CLEAR])() =
{zg_usartCtrlRead, zg_usartCtrlWrite, zg_usartCtrlClr};

int (*const usart_frame_table[USART_READ_WRITE_CLEAR])() =
{zg_usartFrameRead, zg_usartFrameWrite, zg_usartFrameClr};

int (*const usart_trig_ctrl_table[USART_READ_WRITE_CLEAR])() =
{zg_usartTrigctrlRead, zg_usartTrigctrlWrite, zg_usartTrigctrlClr};
```

As you can see, the functions are for accessing a usart peripheral on a hardware level and are arranged in the table in the order of read/write/clear.

What I am attempting to do is have another jump table of jump tables, this way I can either run through initializing all the usart's registers in startup or simply change a single register later if desired.

i.e.

```
<datatype> (*usart_peripheral_table[<number of jump tables>])() = 
{usart_ctrl_table, usart_frame_table, usart_trig_ctrl_table};
```

This way I can expose that table to my middleware layer, which will help maintain a standard across changing HALs, and also I can use a define to index this table i.e.

```
fn_ptr = usart_peripheral_table[CTRL_TABLE]
fn_ptr[WRITE](bitmask);
fn_ptr[READ](buffer);
```

As you may have already guessed, I am struggling to figure out how to construct this table. I figured it is one of two things:

1. Another simple array of pointers, as even a jump table itself is just an array of pointers. Hence my initialization would be:

   ```
   const int* (*usart_peripheral_table[<number of jump tables])() = 
   {usart_ctrl_table, usart_frame_table, usart_trig_ctrl_table};
   ```

However this doesn't seem to be working. Then I thought:

2. An array of pointers to pointers. So I tried all kinds of combos:

   ```
    const int**(*usart_perip...


    const int**(usart_perip...


   const int** (*usart_peripheral_table[<number of jump tables])() = 
   {&usart_ctrl_table, &usart_frame_table[0], usart_trig_ctrl_table};
   ```

Nothing seems to work. Do I need to store the address of the lower jump tables in yet another pointer before assigning that variable to a pointer-to-pointer array? i.e.

```
    int* fn_ptr = usart_ctrl_table;


    <dataytype>(*const usart_periph[<number>])() = {fn_ptr};
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

MM25

EDIT:

```
const int** (*const peripheral_table[1])() =
{&usart_ctrl_table[0]};


const int** (*const peripheral_table[1])() =
{usart_ctrl_table};
```

The above both give the error "initialization from incomaptible pointer type", as do all other combinations I have tried

Comment: Regarding "what is the correct approach" - you answered your question.  You want multiple, parallel tables.  That's fine.  So probably the best approach is to define a pointer which can be configured to point to one or another of those tables at runtime.  Q: What exactly was the problem when you tried this approach?  Q: Can you show is the relevant code, and the exact error message (if applicable)?

Comment: added edit for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `*` like you added `[]` when defining an array.

```
int zg_usartCtrlRead();
int zg_usartCtrlWrite();
int zg_usartCtrlClr();
int zg_usartFrameRead();
int zg_usartFrameWrite();
int zg_usartFrameClr();
int zg_usartTrigctrlRead();
int zg_usartTrigctrlWrite();
int zg_usartTrigctrlClr();

int (*const usart_ctrl_table[])() =
{zg_usartCtrlRead, zg_usartCtrlWrite, zg_usartCtrlClr};

int (*const usart_frame_table[])() =
{zg_usartFrameRead, zg_usartFrameWrite, zg_usartFrameClr};

int (*const usart_trig_ctrl_table[])() =
{zg_usartTrigctrlRead, zg_usartTrigctrlWrite, zg_usartTrigctrlClr};

int (* const * const usart_peripheral_table[])() = 
{usart_ctrl_table, usart_frame_table, usart_trig_ctrl_table};
```

Usage:

```
usart_peripheral_table[1][2](5, 1, 3, 5, 6);
```

Btw, an empty parameter list on function declaration `()` means unspecified number and type of arguments. Do `(void)` if you want no arguments passed to your function.

This:

```
const int* (*usart_peripheral_table[<number of jump tables])();
```

Is an array of functions pointers that take unspecified number of arguments and return a pointer to constant integer.

This:

```
const int** (*usart_peripheral_table[<number of jump tables])()
```

Is an array of function pointers that take unspecified number of arguments and return a pointer to a pointer to a constant integer.

You can also go with a 2D array:

```
int (* const usart_peripheral_table_2d[][3])() = {
    {
        zg_usartCtrlRead, zg_usartCtrlWrite, zg_usartCtrlClr, 
    }, {
        zg_usartFrameRead, zg_usartFrameWrite, zg_usartFrameClr,
    }, {
        zg_usartTrigctrlRead, zg_usartTrigctrlWrite, zg_usartTrigctrlClr,
    },
};
```

But maybe you want to write accessor functions that will return a pointer to an array of functions. Nothing simpler!

```
#include <stddef.h>

int (*usart_ctrl_table_get(size_t idx))() {
    return usart_ctrl_table[idx];
}

int (*usart_frame_table_get(size_t idx))() {
    return usart_frame_table[idx];
}

int (*usart_trig_ctrl_table_get(size_t idx))() {
    return usart_trig_ctrl_table[idx];
}

int (* const (* const usart_peripheral_table_indirect[])(size_t))() = {
    usart_ctrl_table_get, 
    usart_frame_table_get,
    usart_trig_ctrl_table_get,
};
```

Usage sample:

```
int main() {
    usart_peripheral_table_indirect[2](1)();
}
```

Comment: The first part of your answer seems to be the correct way to do this. However, I am confused. Why did I need to add a second const keyword and why couldn't I just add another asterix operator in front of const i.e. ...(**const ... Could you explain further why this also creates a 2d array, as illustrated in your 'Usage' example? Thanks :)

Comment: re: second EDIT: hahaha... maybe I want to make a table of pointers to a pointer which points to another pointer and then also points at the moon which points to another pointer!! XD

Comment: Arrays in most context "decay" or "shall be converted" (read as: magically convert) to a pointer to the first member of an array. Grab some good article on the net if you don't really get that. My `usart_peripheral_table` is an array of pointers to function pointers, and `a[b]` operator is equal to `*(a + b)` the rest comes from pointer arithmetics (also a good topic to read about in C).

Comment: yeh definitely understand decay, that's why I initially thought it was either another simple pointer array or an array of pointers to pointers... glad I was at least on the right track here. Thanks so much for your answer, I will study it more carefully and apply what I have learnt :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find that defining a `typedef` for your function pointers makes your code easier to read and maintain (although I’ve seen people recommend against it too):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UART_RWC 3U

typedef int (*uart_ctl_func)(void);

int uart_read(void)
{
  printf("Read.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

int uart_write(void)
{
  printf("Write.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return(0);
}

int uart_clear(void)
{
  printf("Clear.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

uart_ctl_func uart_ctl_jump_table[][UART_RWC] = {
  { uart_read, uart_write, uart_clear },
  { uart_read, uart_write, uart_clear }
};

int main(void)
{
  uart_ctl_jump_table[0][1](); // Write.
  uart_ctl_jump_table[1][0](); // Read.
  uart_ctl_jump_table[1][2](); // Clear.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The next step might be to make the jump table a `struct` so you end up writing `Uart_ctl_table.frame.read()`, or to at least define an `enum` for the constants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UART_RWC 3U

typedef int (*uart_ctl_func)(void);

int uart_read(void)
{
  printf("Read.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

int uart_write(void)
{
  printf("Write.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return(0);
}

int uart_clear(void)
{
  printf("Clear.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

typedef struct {
  uart_ctl_func read;
  uart_ctl_func write;
  uart_ctl_func clear;
} uart_ctl_set_t;

typedef struct {
  uart_ctl_set_t ctrl;
  uart_ctl_set_t frame;
  uart_ctl_set_t trig;
} uart_ctl_table_t;

const uart_ctl_table_t uart_ctl_table = {
  .ctrl = { uart_read, uart_write, uart_clear },
  .frame = { uart_read, uart_write, uart_clear },
  .trig = { uart_read, uart_write, uart_clear }
};

int main(void)
{
  uart_ctl_table.ctrl.write(); // Write.
  uart_ctl_table.frame.read(); // Read.
  uart_ctl_table.trig.clear(); // Clear.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Definitely agree, althought I usually just wait till I really understand what I'm doing with a particular experiment before typedef'ing... just to make sure it's all in front of me while I play around with ideas.